# onclick stay focused untill click another component from the area

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I try to make a chat-app, now i'm trying to implement the cheats and when user click on one chat, styles must change and remain until the user focus it's gonna to another chat

[image]

In my example let's assume someone clicked on User 2. The chat changed style and now have the style that should have when someone open that chat. How can i make the style to stay like that until someone open another chat? I didn't find any css propriety or some react tricks.

```css
.userChatBubbles {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 5%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.allOfMessage {
   
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: 13%;

    margin-bottom: 1px;
}

.messageBubleNEWMSG {
    
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;

    width: 90%;
    height: 80%;
    font-size: 15px;
    background: #1d1335;
    opacity: 1;
    border-radius: 2%;
    padding-left: 4%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.messageBuble {
   
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
  
    width: 90%;
    height: 80%;
 
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;

    padding-left: 4%;
    margin-right: 10%;
}

.photo {
   
    background: green;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    margin-top: 2%;
    border-radius: 10%;
    margin-right: 6%;
}

.messageBubleNEWMSG.personNameAndMsg.personName {
    color: green !important;
    margin-top: 200%;
}

.messageBuble .personNameAndMsg h3 {
    color: #c2b4da;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.messageBuble .personNameAndMsg p {
    color: #514b64;
    margin-top: -8%;
    /* margin-top: 1%; */
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 200;
}

.messageBubleNEWMSG .personNameAndMsg h3 {
    color: #e1dbed;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.messageBubleNEWMSG .personNameAndMsg p {
    color: #736f83;
    margin-top: -8%;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    /* margin-top: 1%; */
}

.messageTime {
    margin-left: auto;

    color: #6e6d73;
}
```

```html
  
 <div class='userChatBubbles'>
                <div class='allOfMessage'>
                    <div class='messageBuble'>
                        <div class='photo'></div>
                        <div class='personNameAndMsg'>
                            <h3>User</h3>

                            <p> When can we hangout?</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class='messageTime'>6m</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            
                <div class='allOfMessage'>
                    <div class='messageBubleNEWMSG'>
                        <div class='photo'></div>
                        <div class='personNameAndMsg'>
                            <h3>User 2</h3>

                            <p> When can we hang out?</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class='messageTime'>6m</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                 <div class='allOfMessage'>
                    <div class='messageBuble'>
                        <div class='photo'></div>
                        <div class='personNameAndMsg'>
                            <h3>User 3</h3>

                            <p> When can we hangout?</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class='messageTime'>6m</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: If you want the style to stay even after any other button is clicked(except the other chat window), then I think you need Javascript.

Comment: @TusharShahi thank you, is here a way i can do this using React?

Comment: I did this to nav buttons but i have an Object in useState for this but i can't think how to use an useState and how to design the object, if i have for example 100 chats.